Which key was used to open my user account
This is question is an upgrade attempt of Find out which ssh key was used to access an account -- Some scripts for proper installation
Where I

use rsyslog to generate separated log file, readable by group user,
modify .bashrc for adding a $SSH_USER_KEY in user environment.

Unfortunately on systems using systemd and journalctl I have to manually install rsyslog which are no more installed by default.
So yes, if I install rsyslog package, I could resolve my problem, my scripts will run again but,
I wonder if there could exist some more appropriated (systemd) way for permitting user to see the hash of key used for the last connection.

Enable the "ExposeAuthInfo" option in your sshd configuration

/etc/ssh/sshd_config
ExposeAuthInfo yes

The user will then get an $SSH_USER_AUTH environment variable, which points to a file containing the public key (or Kerberos principal name, or whatever else) that was used for authentication.

% cat $SSH_USER_AUTH
gssapi-with-mic grawity@EXAMPLE.COM


% cat $SSH_USER_AUTH
publickey ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIF4k/zikGJLxSTxck...

This option is new in OpenSSH 7.6 (2017). If you're running an older version – install rsyslog.
(Although in this situation, anything rsyslog does could also be achieved with a systemd .service that runs ExecStart=journalctl -u sshd -f | grep public > /var/log/pubkeys.)
